# Peewee how can I IGNORE columns using get_or_create? Duplicates

Tags: orm, peewee

I have four columns
id, name, industry, url

I am asking whether there is parameter that ignores a column in get_or_create. Not a unique together constraint.
Since url can change, I want peewee to ignore the column url when adding using get_or_create.

I want it to check whether name and industry are already present in the table. If they are, then it does not add a duplicate entry. If they are not, then it adds a new entry.

Comment: @Shadow - this is a valid question. You were too hasty.

Comment: @coleifer I did not dispute that it was a valid question, just I think it has already been answered. You do not need a default value for the url column for it to be ignored in a duplicate column check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you would want to, in that case, use the `defaults` parameter:

```
Model.get_or_create(
    name='the name',
    industry='the industry',
    defaults={'url': 'https://...'})
```

The above would first attempt to fetch a match on `name` and `industry`. If no match is found, then one is created with the given URL. The above is equivalent to:

```
try:
    m = Model.get(name='the name', industry='the industry')
except Model.DoesNotExist:
    m = Model.create(
        name='the name',
        industry='the industry',
        url='the url')
```